# Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "init_status.icm""

Tags: r

Running the following code from Tim Church blog and getting the this error.  https://timchurches.github.io/blog/posts/2020-03-18-modelling-the-effects-of-public-health-interventions-on-covid-19-transmission-part-2/

```
 Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "init_status.icm""
```

Error says it can't find the function but I see the function in Environment Functions.

[image]

If you load the code and run it does it work for you?  I'm trying to get this baseline scenerio to work and than change the parameters to run different assumptions to simulate the spread of the covid-19 in the population.  Can someone please help?

```
  # Churches (2020, March 18). Tim Churches Health Data Science Blog: Modelling the effects of public health interventions on COVID-19 transmission using R - part 2. Retrieved from https://timchurches.github.io/blog/posts/2020-03-18-modelling-the-effects-of-public-health-interventions-on-covid-19-transmission-part-2/


library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)
library(gt)
library(knitr)
library(devtools)
library(DiagrammeR)
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(tictoc)
suppressMessages(library(EpiModel))
library(incidence)
library(earlyR)

tic("Time to complete")

source_files <- c("_icm.mod.init.seiqhrf.R", "_icm.mod.status.seiqhrf.R", 
                  "_icm.mod.vital.seiqhrf.R", "_icm.control.seiqhrf.R", "_icm.utils.seiqhrf.R", 
                  "_icm.saveout.seiqhrf.R", "_icm.icm.seiqhrf.R")

src_path <- paste0("./_posts/2020-03-18-modelling-the-effects-of-public-health-", 
                   "interventions-on-covid-19-transmission-part-2/")

gist_url <- "https://gist.github.com/timchurches/92073d0ea75cfbd387f91f7c6e624bd7"

local_source <- FALSE

for (source_file in source_files) {
    if (local_source) {
        source(paste(src_path, source_file, sep = ""))
    } else {
        source_gist(gist_url, filename = source_file)
    }
}

# function to set-up and run the baseline simulations
simulate <- function(# control.icm params
    type = "SEIQHRF", 
    nsteps = 366, 
    nsims = 8,
    ncores = 4,
    prog.rand = FALSE,
    rec.rand = FALSE,
    fat.rand = TRUE,
    quar.rand = FALSE,
    hosp.rand = FALSE,
    disch.rand = TRUE,
    infection.FUN = infection.seiqhrf.icm,
    recovery.FUN = progress.seiqhrf.icm,
    departures.FUN = departures.seiqhrf.icm,
    arrivals.FUN = arrivals.icm,
    get_prev.FUN = get_prev.seiqhrf.icm,
    # init.icm params
    s.num = 9997,
    e.num=0,
    i.num = 3,
    q.num=0,
    h.num=0,
    r.num = 0,
    f.num = 0,
    # param.icm params
    inf.prob.e = 0.02, 
    act.rate.e = 10,
    inf.prob.i = 0.05, 
    act.rate.i = 10,
    inf.prob.q = 0.02, 
    act.rate.q = 2.5,                    
    quar.rate = 1/30, 
    hosp.rate = 1/100,
    disch.rate = 1/15,
    prog.rate = 1/10,
    prog.dist.scale = 5,
    prog.dist.shape = 1.5,
    rec.rate = 1/20,
    rec.dist.scale = 35,
    rec.dist.shape = 1.5,
    fat.rate.base = 1/50,
    hosp.cap = 40,
    fat.rate.overcap = 1/25,
    fat.tcoeff = 0.5,
    vital = TRUE,
    a.rate = (10.5/365)/1000, 
    a.prop.e = 0.01,
    a.prop.i = 0.001,
    a.prop.q = 0.01,
    ds.rate = (7/365)/1000, 
    de.rate = (7/365)/1000, 
    di.rate = (7/365)/1000,
    dq.rate = (7/365)/1000,
    dh.rate = (20/365)/1000,
    dr.rate = (7/365)/1000,
    out="mean"
) {

    control <- control.icm(type = type, 
                           nsteps = nsteps, 
                           nsims = nsims,
                           ncores = ncores,
                           prog.rand = prog.rand,
                           rec.rand = rec.rand,
                           infection.FUN = infection.FUN,
                           recovery.FUN = recovery.FUN,
                           arrivals.FUN = arrivals.FUN,
                           departures.FUN = departures.FUN,
                           get_prev.FUN = get_prev.FUN)

    init <- init.icm(s.num = s.num,
                     e.num = e.num,
                     i.num = i.num,
                     q.num = q.num,
                     h.num = h.num,
                     r.num = r.num,
                     f.num = f.num)

    param <-  param.icm(inf.prob.e = inf.prob.e, 
                        act.rate.e = act.rate.e,
                        inf.prob.i = inf.prob.i, 
                        act.rate.i = act.rate.i,
                        inf.prob.q = inf.prob.q, 
                        act.rate.q = act.rate.q,                    
                        quar.rate = quar.rate,
                        hosp.rate = hosp.rate,
                        disch.rate = disch.rate,
                        prog.rate = prog.rate,
                        prog.dist.scale = prog.dist.scale,
                        prog.dist.shape = prog.dist.shape,
                        rec.rate = rec.rate,
                        rec.dist.scale = rec.dist.scale,
                        rec.dist.shape = rec.dist.shape,
                        fat.rate.base = fat.rate.base,
                        hosp.cap = hosp.cap,
                        fat.rate.overcap = fat.rate.overcap,
                        fat.tcoeff = fat.tcoeff,
                        vital = vital,
                        a.rate = a.rate, 
                        a.prop.e = a.prop.e,
                        a.prop.i = a.prop.i,
                        a.prop.q = a.prop.q,
                        ds.rate = ds.rate, 
                        de.rate = de.rate, 
                        di.rate = di.rate,
                        dq.rate = dq.rate,
                        dh.rate = dh.rate,
                        dr.rate = dr.rate)

    sim <- icm.seiqhrf(param, init, control)
    sim_df <- as.data.frame(sim, out=out)

    return(list(sim=sim, df=sim_df))
}

baseline_sim <- simulate(ncores = 4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the numbers of cores (ncores) to 1 in both functions (simulate and baseline) and succeed it.

control.icm actually set the core to 1 as you can see it in the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnx69.png